# Optimising c++ arrays and vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

Im trying to opptimise this peice of code as its a small section of a longer code for speed rather than memory. How best would I do that. I was thinking to use set the v_vtx vector to be able to just to define the chitemp array.

```
double chitemp[nvert1][2];
for (int i=0;i<nvert1;i++){
  chitemp[i][1]=v_vtx[i];
  chitemp[i][0]=chi2->at(v_vtx[i]);
}
for (int k = 0; k < nvert1; k++){
  for( int p = k+1; p < nvert1; p++){
  if( chitemp[k][0] > chitemp[p][0]){
    swap(chitemp[k][0], chitemp[p][0]);
    swap(chitemp[k][1], chitemp[p][1]);
  }
 }
}
```

edit:

Im trying to sort chi2 (double) into order and know which v_vtx (int) links to the chi2 value

Comment: at least post the type of those objects, and describe their utilization (what are they meant to be used)

Comment: Are you optimizing for space or speed?

Comment: Instead of a two dimensional array, you could have a single dimensional array of structures.  Think about the data that is accessed most frequently.  You need to design the data container so that the most frequently accessed data is closest to each other.  This will help speed up the processor's data cache fetching.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead store your values as pairs (using `std::array` is optional, but offers a richer interface than an inbuilt array):

```
std::array<std::pair<double>, nvert1> chitemp;
for (size_t i = 0; i < nvert1; ++i) {
    chitemp[i].second = v_vtx[i];
    chitemp[i].first = chi2->at(v_vtx[i]);
}
```

Then, use...

```
std::sort(chitemp.begin(), chitemp.end());
```

...instead of your (inefficient) home-grown bubble-sort.